# Mostrar un header u otro según url

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un sitio que tiene una tienda online, entre otras cosas. Quiero colocar un script para un chatbot únicamente en las páginas de la tienda. Para ello, tengo el `header.php` sin el script y un `header-tienda.php` donde está el código del script.

Ahora yo debería colocar una condición en `index.php` para que si, la url empieza por `misitio/tienda` o `misitio/categorias` se muestre `header-tienda.php` o de lo contrario se muestre `header.php`.

(es decir, deberia mostrarse el chatbot tanto en `misitio/tienda` como en `misitio/tienda/legales` y todo lo que tenga `misitio/tienda` por ejemplo, lo mismo con `categorias/`).

Cual sería la condición correcta?

```
if(``condicion-que-necesito``){
  get_header('header-tienda');
} else {
  get_header('header');
}
```

Comment: Podrias obtener la URL y luego usar expresiones regulares

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar de qué modo accedes a la URL y qué contenido obtienes? Es importante para este caso, para saber cómo tratar la cadena que estás obteniendo. Piulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar wp_parse_url para obtener el path de la url, de esta forma:

```
$url_parse_head = wp_parse_url( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
```

Si tu url es por ejemplo, mi-sitio.com/tienda la variable deberia devolverte lo siguiente:

```
array (size=1)
  'path' => string '/tienda/' (length=5)
```

entonces si llamas a la variable `$url_parse_head` y le pasas el `path` deberias de recibir esto.

```
echo $url_parse_head['path'];
```

Resultado

```
/tienda/
```

Con eso solo aplicas una condicional o varias segun necesites

```
if ( echo $url_parse_head['path'] == '/tienda/' ) {

    get_header();

} else {

    get_header( 'custom' );

}
```

Otra forma seria usando la función nativa de wordpress `get_the_permalink();` entonces puedes hacer esto, `$url = get_the_permalink();`

```
if ( echo $url == 'mi-sitio.com/tienda/' ) {

    get_header();

} else {

    get_header( 'custom' );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si has usado WooCommerce para la tienda puedes usar:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
  get_header('header-tienda');
} else {
  get_header('header');
}
```

Retorna verdadero cuando la página usa plantillas de WooCommerce (productos, categorías,...). El carrito y el checkout son páginas estándar con shortcodes y, por lo tanto, no están incluidas. Para ello tienes otras opciones que pueden ser válidas si no usas WooCommerce que es usar plantillas de página para carrito y checkout (lo mismo para las páginas legales) o directamente IDs de página:

```
if ( is_woocommerce() || is_page_template('mi-plantilla.php') || is_page(42) ) {
  get_header('header-tienda');
} else {
  get_header('header');
}
```

Encontrarás más información aquí:

Condicionales WooCommerce:  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/
Condicionales WordPress: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags
Plantillas: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Igualmente, en vez de usar dos headers, si la única diferencia son los scripts, te recomiendo utilizar condicionales para la función wp_enqueue_script().